# SQL Database Mirroring Number Restriction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring

We are thinking of incorporating Database Mirroring. Company does not have time/budget for AlwaysOn Availability Groups. We currently conduct 24hr backup/restore from one server to another secondary server in geographical location. We want to reduce 24hr gap. Will utilize Asynchronous High Performance Mode.

We have around 50 databases, that we will move from Principal Server A to Mirror Server B.
Does SQL Server have any limitations on number of databases we can incorporate?

Company only consumes 1-2TB a yr, 50 million rows max in table, 200GB memory, 50 Cores on Principles,  same with Mirror server

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/prerequisites-restrictions-and-recommendations-for-database-mirroring?view=sql-server-2017), there isn't a *technical* limitation on the number of databases you can mirror. The more you have, the more you will have to manage, obviously.

As noted in that link, mirroring is deprecated and will be removed from SQL Server at some point in the future. Microsoft themselves recommend against implementing a new solution using mirroring as a result. You should consider alternatives such as log shipping, which may give you the protection you need (depending upon your SLAs, RTO, RPO, etc.).